# How to update each url in db table from one address to another?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry I have very little knowledge of SQL,

I have db `my_table` that I would like to update the entries of `guid` in table `wp_posts` from `http://local.localhost` to `http://livesiteaddress.com`

Can anyone advise what SQL I need to make this change to all entries?

**SQL**

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET guid=http://livesiteaddress.com
WHERE guid=http://local.localhost
```

I'm not sure however how I keep the additional params being added to each guid, example url:

```
http://local.localhost/?page_id=6
```

Comment: RTFM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_%28SQL%29

Answer (score -1):

A good question should had showed some effort done, and problems face till now, simple query like this should have done:

```
update wp_posts set guid = "http://livesiteaddress.com" where guid like "local.localhost/?page_id=%";
```

Comment: Hi, will this replace the http://.. and keep the param parts of each url? http://local.localhost/?page_id=6

Comment: There is no column named `gu_id`. The OP has already tried this.

Comment: What i mean is will this override all my entries like http://local.localhost/?page_id=6 and replace each one with just http://livesiteaddress.com ?

Comment: For that, you will have to use `CONCAT` function of mysql. reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat),

Comment: @Kermit: There is a column name `gu_id`, and when I had posted the answer styler hadn't put this in the question, now I have updated it as par the discussion with styler.

@styler: I have updated it, is this what you are looking for??

Comment: @saurabh where do you see `gu_id`... there's only `guid` (no underscore).

Comment: @Kermit, oh that, sorry about that, thanks for noticing and pointing that out.

Comment: @saurabh hmm, doesnt seem to work that great, simply because I've realised there is actually a mix of urls - /?page_id=6 , 6-revision-v1/ , ?post_type=book-review&#038;p=45 , wp-content/uploads/2014/04/announce3.jpg etc etc

Comment: In that case, you can do just this:  `where guid like "local.localhost/?"`

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct, when I run this it affects no rows. See screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/072cfk5v1l4wwj3/Screenshot%202014-04-26%2021.04.09.png should I be selecting anything?

Comment: Sorry, It should be `where guid like "local.localhost/?%`, you can read more about like queries [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).